# How to Update file name in FileField after file is uploaded on s3 via presigned post URL in Django?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-models, django-storage

I have integrated [django-storages](https://pypi.org/project/django-storages/) in **Django** Project. for **large file** sizes, I have used a [pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) to upload files from externally without taking a load on my server.

by pre-signed URL, Files uploaded successfully in the s3 bucket AWS, after uploading the file in s3 I need to update the name of the file in **FileField**.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need something like, using the `boto3` library to retrieve the file from S3 and `os` library to rename the file.

```
import boto3
import os

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

uploaded_file = s3.get_object(Bucket='your-bucket-name', Key='object-key')

new_filename = 'new_file_name.txt'
os.rename(uploaded_file['Body'].name, new_filename)

...

with open(new_filename, 'rb') as f:
    file_obj = File(f, name=new_filename)

    my_model.file_field_name = file_obj
    my_model.save()
```

Comment: If we get the file from s3 and load it into memory that's not probably a good idea, because in my case file size is very high that's why I have used a pre-signed URL for upload externally. @Panos Angelopoulos

Comment: In this case, you can try to read the file in chunks and write each chunk to the new file, `with open(new_filename, 'wb') as f: for chunk in uploaded_file['Body'].iter_chunks(): f.write(chunk)`

Comment: already pre-signed url manage this externally with aws api.